# Adding Google Conversion code to WordPress Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7

I found a tutorial for adding Google Conversion code to WordPress Contact Form 7 plugin which can be found [here](http://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/).

Currently I've added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".wpcf7-form").submit(function(){
        var google_conversion_id = "12345678910";
        var google_conversion_label = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
        var image = new Image(1,1); 
        image.src = "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/"+google_conversion_id+"/?label="+google_conversion_label+"&script=0";
    });
</script>
```

to my footer, but it doesn't send correct results. Could someone help me out with what I should add to my Contact Form Plugin, through the control panel of WordPress, to make my Analytics show correct results. I would not prefer redirecting to another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on right track. As this script runs you get your results recorded at server.

1. The **easiest and most common way** to achieve this is to place the
   script on a separate page(generally a thank-you.php) and redirect
   user to that page so after completion of his activity we can run
   this script and record this activity. **OR**
2. **The other way**(*a tricky one though*) is to make this script run on the
   same page using ajax/javascript after user's activity.

If you want to set it without any redirection you may find this helpful.

[Google Conversion Tracking Without Redirection](https://17path.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/google-conversion-tracking-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

The analytic code should be like this format:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);  // value is a number.
```

(where the last 2 parameters are optional)

So, we just need to make the Contact Form 7's Additional settings code like this:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Landing Page', 'Submit');"
//here 'Landing Page' or 'Submit' are just for sample;
```

If you want to learn more:
[Event tracking in WordPress Contact Form 7 (Universal Analytics)](https://www.impression.co.uk/blog/825/event-tracking-wpcf7-universal-analytics/) and
[Google Event Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Answer (score 0):

I did this in three simple steps:

1. In the CF7 Plugin (additional settings):

on_sent_ok: "run_conversion_code();"

2. In header.php (or in a js file):

   ```
       function run_conversion_code()

               {
                   $ = jQuery;
                   var a = "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
                   $.post(a, {action: 'run_conversion_code'}).done(function(data){

                       $('body').append(data);

                   });

                   console.log('conversion code running'); 

               }

       </script>
   ```
3. functions.php

   function run_conversion_code()

   ```
   {

       ?>


           <script type="text/javascript">




           /* <![CDATA[ */

           var google_conversion_id = 962XXX263;

           var google_conversion_language = "en";

           var google_conversion_format = "3";

           var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";

           var google_conversion_label = "TsaNCM6dq1wQ99HzygM";

           var google_remarketing_only = false;

           /* ]]> */

           </script>

           <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">

           </script>

           <noscript>

           <div style="display:inline;">

           <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/962390263/?label=TsaNCM6dq1wQ99HzygM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>

           </div>

           </noscript>
       <?php   die();


   }
   ```

   add_action( 'wp_ajax_run_conversion_code', 'run_conversion_code' );

   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_run_conversion_code', 'run_conversion_code');