# Goal tracking with contact form 7 in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form, contact-form-7, goal-tracking

I am trying to set up goal tracking on contact form submissions in WordPress with Contact Form 7 Plugin.

I've got Universal Tracking all set-up and I've added the following to the additional section on the contact form in question:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'sent');"
```

I've then gone in Analytics and made a goal to track the event of submission however after testing the form and verifying Analytics doesn't seem to pick up on the results.

Am I missing something here?

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Here is an answer about this: [Contact Form 7][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957175/adding-google-conversion-code-to-wordpress-contact-form-7/20634265#20634265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked in the Real-Time reports to see if you can see your event hits? You would have to check within 30 minutes of triggering your event though because RT reports only has a 30 minute "memory".

Comment: Hi @nyuen, thanks for the reply. I've just checked after doing a contact form submission and you are right, the goal conversions are being tracked in real-time. However, since writing this question I can see only one conversion in Conversions -> Goals and there have been at least 5-10. Do you know why it's tracking in real-time but not saving the data?